# Persisted object showing incorrect date format if retrieved in same session -Spring ,Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

In my Spring/Hibernate application, I am persisting an object with date variable.

Below is the JPA annotation for that date column.

```
@Column(name = "EFFECTIVE_DATE", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
private Date                effectiveDate;
```

After persisting, if retrieve the same object date column shows as below format.

Fri Mar 30 10:59:21 AEDT 2018

But if I logged out of the application and if I log in again then it showing in the correct format as below if I retrieve the same previous object.

```
03-30-2018
```

[Retrived date objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDLh6.jpg)

I am not sure what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved by refreshing the object after persist.

```
hibernateUtils.getSession().persist(requiredObject);
transaction.commit();
hibernateUtils.getSession().refresh(requiredObject);
```